# unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address in use (98)

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I can't start php7-fpm in supervisor.
The error log:

> unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address in > use (98)

In browser:

> localhost:8090 is error: 502 Bad Gateway

netstat -tulnp

```
tcp     0    0 0.0.0.0:8080         0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      13/nginx
tcp     0    0 0.0.0.0:80           0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      13/nginx
tcp     0    0 0.0.0.0:8090         0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      13/nginx
tcp     0    0 :::3000              :::*           LISTEN      11/node
tcp     0    0 :::7000              :::*           LISTEN      10/node
```

ps aux

```
/ # ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 {bootloader} /bin/sh /boot/bootloader
    8 root      0:01 {supervisord} /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/supervisord
   62 root      0:00 /bin/sh
   92 root      0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
   93 root      0:00 nginx: worker process
   94 root      0:00 nginx: worker process
  122 root      0:00 ps aux
```

php-fpm.d/www/conf

```
[www]

user = nobody
group = nobody

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000

pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 5

pm.start_servers = 2

pm.min_spare_servers = 1

pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/page1

```
server {
        listen      8090;
        root        /usr/bin;
        server_name localhost;
        access_log  /dev/null;
        error_log   /dev/null;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.0:7000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.(gif) {
                root /var/lib;
        }

}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/page2

```
server {
  server_name localhost;
  root        /www;
  index       index.php;
  access_log  /dev/null;
  error_log   /dev/null;

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires       max;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files     $uri =404;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

Where is error? I don't just any idea.

Comment: some time ago (not certain now) both fpm and xdebug (php storm) shipped with 9000 as the listen port.  So if you have an xdebug client, or IDE, there could be a collision. And, it would be rather simple to change the listen port for fpm no ?  see if this water runs deeper than it looks :)

Comment: Also check if you have another group (other than `www`) which could also listen on 9000.

Comment: In php-fpm.d/www/conf user and group is nobody. I have no idea what might be on port 9000. No netstat command shows anything on this port.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg And if I change the port from 9000 to another port, e.g. 8999, 9001, the error is the same: unable to bind... '127.0.0.1:8999' or '127.0.0.1:9001

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was PHPStorm with xdebug listening on port 9000.

You can stop it by going to:
Settings > PHP > Debug

and click "Stop Listening" under item 3. in the list on the top.

To avoid such problems you should reconfigure your xdebug and PHPStorm to use a different port.